# Custom widget doesn't show when added via the widget menu

Tags: magento2.2, widget

I created a custom widget and it works when I add it on a page. But I want to use it more then once and prefer adding it in de content -> widget menu. But when I do that I get the following error:

```
1 exception(s):Exception #0(Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'block', attribute 'class': [facet 'pattern'] The value 'duo\Veritas\Block\Widget\carousel' is not accepted by the pattern '[A-Z][_a-zA-Z\d]*(\\[A-Z][_a-zA-Z\d]*)*'.Line: 748
Element 'block', attribute 'class': 'duo\Veritas\Block\Widget\carousel' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'blockClassType'.Line: 748
```

I have tried with a template file and without here are  my classes.

widget.xml file (used for both methods):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widgets xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Widget:etc/widget.xsd">
<widget id="duo_veritas" class="duo\Veritas\Block\Widget\carousel" placeholder_image="Magento_Cms::images/widget_block.png">
    <label translate="true">Carousel image</label>
    <description translate="true">Picture and text for the homepage carousel</description>
    <parameters>
        <parameter name="photo" xsi:type="block" visible="true" sort_order="10">
            <label translate="true">Photo</label>
            <description translate="true">Contact photo</description>

            <block class="duo\Veritas\Block\Adminhtml\Widget\ImageChooser">
                <data>
                    <item name="button" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="open" xsi:type="string">Choose Image...</item>
                    </item>
                </data>
            </block>
        </parameter>
    </parameters>   
</widget>
```

First method:

```
<?php
namespace duo\Veritas\Block\Widget;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
class Carousel extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text implements \Magento\Widget\Block\BlockInterface
{


protected function _beforeToHtml()
{
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

    $storeManager = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager');
    $mediaPath = $storeManager-> getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA );


    $url = $mediaPath . $this->getData('photo');

    $this->setText(sprintf('<img src="%s"/>', $url)
    );
    return parent::_beforeToHtml();
}
}
```

Second method (widget class):

```
<?php
namespace duo\Veritas\Block\Widget;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Widget\Block\BlockInterface;
class Carousel extends Template implements BlockInterface
{
  protected $_template = "widget/picture.phtml";
}
```

Second method template file:

```
<?php
if($this->getData('photo')){
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

    $storeManager = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager');
    $mediaPath = $storeManager-> getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA );
    $url = $mediaPath . $this->getData('photo');
}
?>
<?php if($url): ?>
  <img src="<?php echo $url ?>"/>
<?php endif;?>
```

Both methods show when I add it on a page but not when I add it to the via the content->widget menu I get the same errors.

Comment: search blockClassType inside view/layout files in the module duo\Veritas  its xml error

Comment: See my edit, I don't think it's an xml error because it works when I add it to a page in the content->pages menu.

Comment: please check here https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11110

Comment: I saw that also but that's not the problem, as you can see I have no leading backslash in my class attribute

Comment: in first method \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text to \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template should be

Comment: Doesn't work that's why I tried the second method

Comment: first of all please follow naming convention of modules use "Duo" not "duo"

Comment: Ok it was the naming convention but not with "Duo" (I did change it) but with the Carousel. Thanks

Comment: Did it work now ?